# How can I call a delegate that takes multiple parameters if I have a list of mixed type that matches the delegate parameter pattern?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, interpreter

I'm writing a simple interpreter.

For function calls I have a hashtable that stores delegates, with the function name as the key. When I retrieve a delegate, I can check that the correct parameter types have been input and parsed to pass to the function.

However, these parameters are in a list of mixed type and the delegate parameters are declared normally. How can I call any of the delegates with this list of parameters?
e.g.

```
private Dictionary<string, Delegate> _functions = new Dictionary<String, Delegate>();
public string exFunc(int num, string text)
{
     return num;
}
AddToDictionary(exFunc); //this is a method that calculates the correct delegate signature for any method and adds to _functions
List<paramTypes> parameters = new List<paramTypes>() {5,"hello"};
Delegate d = _functions["exFunc"];
```

Is there a way to do something like the following, given that the delegate parameter signature has been checked so that the list of parameters has the correct types?:

```
var res = d(ToSingleParams(parameters));
```

I looked into the "params" keyword but it is only for arrays of a single type that I can tell.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can call `delegate.Invoke(instance, arrayParameters)` method and pass instance and parameters

Comment: Thanks Sergey. But do I need to use DynamicInvoke instead? Or can I use a methodinfo of the function to create a more specific delegate?

Comment: Oh, yes, you are totally right. Correct method name is `DynamicInvoke` and it you can pass parameters to this method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke(v=vs.110).aspx . `Invoke` method exists in delegate inheritors, and base `Delegate` hasn't such method. Here is working example - https://dotnetfiddle.net/n01FKB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer. You need to use [DynamicInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) method to call it dynamically. It has `params object[]` parameter that can be used for method parameters. In your sample it would be like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Delegate> _functions = new Dictionary<String, Delegate>();
public string exFunc(int num, string text)
{
     return num;
}
AddToDictionary(exFunc); //this is a method that calculates the correct delegate signature for any method and adds to _functions
List<paramTypes> parameters = new List<paramTypes>() {5,"hello"};
Delegate d = _functions["exFunc"];

d.DynamicInvoke(parameters.ToArray());
```

And here is working sample with `DynamicInvoke` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/n01FKB

Comment: Thanks Sergey! Is there a lot of overhead using dynamicInvoke? Do you think it would be worth creating an inherited delegate from the method descriptor and using plain invoke() instead?

Comment: Beware. `parameters` should be `parameters.ToArray()` if `parameters` is a `List<object>` or `List<SomeReferenceType>`. Or else `parameters` should have type `object[]` itself.

Comment: There will be a small overhead. It will be slower than usual method calls, but shouldn't make a big deal, if you don't call it a lot each second. As possible optimization, you can make an Expression, compile it and save it as `Action`. But not sure that you need it